# Auto tab completion with sftp

Tags: autocomplete, sftp

I've been using sftp to transfer files. I have used sftp on both my mac and linux PC. When used on linux, auto completion works with tabs. When used on mac, auto completion does not work with tabs. The tab key just indents.

Does anyone know how to change this setting?

Answer (score 5):

The MAC openssh client is not compiled with the "autocomplete" support (the `configure` switch `--with-libedit`).

You can either recompile the openssh on your mac (if there is `libedit` on mac), or find whether somebody else did it already (`brew`?).

Comment: how can recompile that?